# How to overcome RNG and finally have the last 2 coins?

Tags: achievements, coin-crypt

Coin Crypt - I'm **struggling** to finish to *100%*

Basically I won the game with every character and beat every boss (peak and forge) I earned every single achievement except the one that need everyone else to be earned to unlock it and the "all coin" achievement...

I'm giving, *on a journey to forge* like 1000 to 2500 to each deity and duplicating keys to open everything and going into every walls to find every secrets... but no new coins... no sire ...

On the road to the mountain I give like (100 up to 2 deity), graveyard 100/300 up to 2/4 deity and mountain depend of the luck if I got good RNG maybe 200 each or 300... and nothing ... every single time the same coins.

So I'm getting bored right now, when you know that a full run (killing everything, looting every secret, spending and duplicating money for deity) takes me around an hour for forge and 45mins for peak ... man ...

Help please :'(

Comment: forget it ... i message the dev... there are some problem of register coin and stuff. ... thanks for the help though ! (sarcasm on)

Comment: lol, time to overcome your inner OCD :)